# Fatal SIGNAL 11 Android baseApi.init()

Tags: android, fatal-error

In my android application I run tesseract engine for ocr. I have tested it long times and it was working right. Today I got an error: Fatal Signal 11 and it seems to be in this function baseApi.init(). I use two languages eng+ell. What can I do to solve this? My log File is here:

```
09-09 17:40:24.710: D/dalvikvm(7446): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 601K, 9% free 17303K/18972K, paused 25ms, total 28ms
09-09 17:40:24.790: I/dalvikvm-heap(7446): Grow heap (frag case) to 54.495MB for 38340880-byte allocation
09-09 17:40:24.810: D/dalvikvm(7446): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 3% free 54733K/56416K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
09-09 17:40:24.840: D/dalvikvm(7446): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 54733K/56416K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 28ms
09-09 17:40:25.150: D/dalvikvm(7446): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 4% free 54681K/56416K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
09-09 17:40:25.190: I/dalvikvm-heap(7446): Grow heap (frag case) to 90.998MB for 38340880-byte allocation
09-09 17:40:25.210: D/dalvikvm(7446): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 92123K/93860K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
09-09 17:40:25.250: D/dalvikvm(7446): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 92124K/93860K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 42ms
09-09 17:40:38.323: D/dalvikvm(7446): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.geo.myapp_1r-1/liblept.so 0x41ffcc90
09-09 17:40:38.323: D/dalvikvm(7446): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.geo.myapp_1r-1/liblept.so 0x41ffcc90
09-09 17:40:38.323: D/dalvikvm(7446): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.geo.myapp_1r-1/libtess.so 0x41ffcc90
09-09 17:40:38.353: D/dalvikvm(7446): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.geo.myapp_1r-1/libtess.so 0x41ffcc90
09-09 17:40:38.353: V/OcrAsyncTask(7446): eng+ell
09-09 17:40:38.353: A/libc(7446): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7568 (AsyncTask #4)
09-09 17:40:38.363: D/ProgressBar(7446): setProgress = 0
09-09 17:40:38.363: D/ProgressBar(7446): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
09-09 17:40:38.363: D/ProgressBar(7446): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
09-09 17:40:38.403: D/ProgressBar(7446): setProgress = 25
09-09 17:40:38.403: D/ProgressBar(7446): setProgress = 25, fromUser = false
09-09 17:40:38.403: D/ProgressBar(7446): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
09-09 17:40:48.593: I/Choreographer(7446): Skipped 608 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Update:
I run it again and now the log file shows:

```
09-09 18:07:17.113: D/ProgressBar(9018): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
09-09 18:07:17.113: D/ProgressBar(9018): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
09-09 18:07:17.113: D/ProgressBar(9018): updateDrawableBounds: right = 834
09-09 18:07:17.113: A/libc(9018): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 9082 (AsyncTask #1)
09-09 18:07:17.113: D/ProgressBar(9018): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 48
09-09 18:07:17.113: D/ProgressBar(9018): updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
```

May the problem related to the AsyncTask and the UI Thread? The sure is that it is always stuck in 25% where is executing baseApi.init().

Update 2nd: Well I run the code for OCR in a different class without using AsyncTask to see if the problem is coming from AsyncTask and it shown me that it's NOT from AsyncTask. The problem is coming from baseApi.init(). Here is my Code:

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.init(languagePath, languageCode);
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
baseApi.end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY!!! I found it. I don't know why but there was a problem in the traineddata files. I deleted them, download them again and test my App. The Fatal Signal Error disappeared and now it's working fine.

Comment: If it is fixes your question then please mark it as a solution